# Canonical link tags appear more than once in AMP Wordpress template site

Tags: wordpress, accelerated-mobile-page

i am seeing two canonical urls in my amp page (generated through wordpress template). What might be the reason for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It may be another plugin having canonical tag feature. So you can deactivate the plugin and then check. Or Also may be any hard code canonical tag written in the header file of the theme.

Comment: Yes thats becouse of a plugin.. got to know how to solve it. Thanks